# Does Flyway support TimescaleDB migrations?

Tags: flyway, timescaledb

I went through Flyway documentation and did not found the TimescaleDB in the supported databases.

Can anyone confirm if Flyway supports TimescaleDB. If not, is there any other CI/CD tool for TimescaleDB?

Answer (score 1):

We haven't formally tested Flyway on TimescaleDB, but it appears that people have successfully used it (as it's essentially an extension of Postgres). The normal Postgres JDBC connection url should work - and if you have problems, submit an issue at http://github.com/flyway/flyway

Comment: See for example https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2826